# syntax error in python dice game

Tags: python

I got a syntax error and can't figure out what is wrong can someone please help

```
    import random

play=input("would you like to play Y/N")

if play==Y:
    dice_roll
if play==N:
    print("try again")
    play=input("would you like to play Y/N")

#declare dice as global and rolls dice 
def dice_roll():
    global p1_dice_1
    global p1_dice_2
    global p1_dice_3
    global p2_dice_1
    global p2_dice_2
    global p2_dice_3
    p1_dice_1=random.randint(1,6)
    p1_dice_2=random.randint(1,6)
    p1_dice_3=random.randint(1,6)
    p2_dice_1=random.randint(1,6)
    p2_dice_2=random.randint(1,6)
    p2_dice_3=random.randint(1,6)
    print_test()
    return

def print_test():
    print("player 1 rolled",p1_dice_1,",",p1_dice_2,"and",p1_dice_3)
    print("palyer 2 rolled",p2_dice_1,",",p2_dice_2,"and",p2_dice_3)
    score_rule()
    return
```

if this could be made less complex I wouldn't mind help

```
 score_rule():
        if p1_dice_1==p1_dice_2==p1_dice_3:
            print("player 1 scored",p1_dice_1+p1_dice_2+p1_dice_3)
        elif p1_dice_1==p1_dice_2=!p1_dice_3:
            print("player 1 scored",p1_dice_1+p1_dice_2-p1_dice_3)
        elif p1_dice_1==p1_dice_3=!p1_dice_2:
            print("player 1 scored",p1_dice_1+p1_dice_3-p1_dice_2)
        elif p1_dice_2==p1_dice_3=!p1_dice_1:
            print("player 1 scored",p1_dice_2+p1_dice_3-p1_dice_1)

    if p2_dice_1==p2_dice_2==p2_dice_3:
        print("player 2 scored",p2_dice_1+p2_dice_2+p2_dice_3)
    elif p2_dice_1==p2_dice_2=!p2_dice_3:
        print("player 2 scored",p2_dice_1+p2_dice_2-p2_dice_3)
    elif p2_dice_1==p2_dice_3=!p2_dice_2:
        print("player 2 scored",p2_dice_1+p2_dice_3-p2_dice_2)
    elif p2_dice_2==p2_dice_3=!p2_dice_1:
        print("player 2 scored",p2_dice_2+p2_dice_3-p2_dice_1)
    return
```

if anyone knows what to do help please I am having to put more words in the question because there is too much code (apparently)

Comment: Let's see the entire error message.

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: I gave this a closer look.  You have many errors in this.  You are now on the learning curve of a new language, and you need to work through these, one at a time.

Note the line number in the error message.  Get a classmate or instructor to help.  Look for examples.

That said, here are a few:
(1) Python requires consistent indentation.  Your first line should not be indented, as it *cannot* be included in a previous block.
(2) Y is a variable; 'Y' is a string constant.  You need the constant here and for 'N'.
(3) dice_roll is a method, not a variable.  It must have parenthese after it.

Comment: (4) You cannot call a method until you've defined it.  This applies to dice_roll and score_rule.  Also, you haven't defined score_rule (forgot 'def').

(5) Variables are local to their blocks.  You've defined p1_dice_1 and its friends inside dice_roll, but those are not visible outside of that method.

That should get you started.  You also need to look up the syntax for "if" conditions.

At the planning level ... have you written an English or near-English description of how you want this to work?  have you drawn a flowchart?  Your program flow suggests that you need to back up to this step.

Answer (score 3):

- `import random` is improperly indented.
- The body of `score_rule` is inconsistently indented.
- `score_rule():` should be `def score_rule():`
- "=!" is not a legal operator. Use "!=".
- `Y` and `N` are not defined. Use string literals.
- `dice_roll` needs to be defined *before* you refer to it. Move your main code so that it appears after your function definitions.
- Function calls require parentheses. Change `dice_roll` to `dice_roll()`.

```
import random

#declare dice as global and rolls dice 
def dice_roll():
    global p1_dice_1
    global p1_dice_2
    global p1_dice_3
    global p2_dice_1
    global p2_dice_2
    global p2_dice_3
    p1_dice_1=random.randint(1,6)
    p1_dice_2=random.randint(1,6)
    p1_dice_3=random.randint(1,6)
    p2_dice_1=random.randint(1,6)
    p2_dice_2=random.randint(1,6)
    p2_dice_3=random.randint(1,6)
    print_test()
    return

def print_test():
    print("player 1 rolled",p1_dice_1,",",p1_dice_2,"and",p1_dice_3)
    print("palyer 2 rolled",p2_dice_1,",",p2_dice_2,"and",p2_dice_3)
    score_rule()
    return

def score_rule():
    if p1_dice_1==p1_dice_2==p1_dice_3:
        print("player 1 scored",p1_dice_1+p1_dice_2+p1_dice_3)
    elif p1_dice_1==p1_dice_2!=p1_dice_3:
        print("player 1 scored",p1_dice_1+p1_dice_2-p1_dice_3)
    elif p1_dice_1==p1_dice_3!=p1_dice_2:
        print("player 1 scored",p1_dice_1+p1_dice_3-p1_dice_2)
    elif p1_dice_2==p1_dice_3!=p1_dice_1:
        print("player 1 scored",p1_dice_2+p1_dice_3-p1_dice_1)

    if p2_dice_1==p2_dice_2==p2_dice_3:
        print("player 2 scored",p2_dice_1+p2_dice_2+p2_dice_3)
    elif p2_dice_1==p2_dice_2!=p2_dice_3:
        print("player 2 scored",p2_dice_1+p2_dice_2-p2_dice_3)
    elif p2_dice_1==p2_dice_3!=p2_dice_2:
        print("player 2 scored",p2_dice_1+p2_dice_3-p2_dice_2)
    elif p2_dice_2==p2_dice_3!=p2_dice_1:
        print("player 2 scored",p2_dice_2+p2_dice_3-p2_dice_1)
    return

play=input("would you like to play Y/N")

if play=='Y':
    dice_roll()
if play=='N':
    print("try again")
    play=input("would you like to play Y/N")
```

Result:

```
would you like to play Y/NY
player 1 rolled 6 , 4 and 5
palyer 2 rolled 3 , 4 and 6
```

You probably also need additional `else` clauses that score rolls when no two dice are equal.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be useful to see the error message

But if that's your code, try

```
if play=='Y':
```

similar for the 'N' statement.

Edit:
Answer 2 also is valid, dice_roll is a function, dice_roll().

Edit again: Someone's come back with a pretty comprehensive answer, refer to his.